# SCNNode scale changes when animation plays using a dae file

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit, collada

Trying to use a dae file in scenekit for my model as well as my animations. When I try to scale the model, it scales correctly. After the animation starts playing, it resets to the original scale. Here is what I am trying to do at the moment:

```
let playerNode = gameScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Player", recursively: true)

let animation = CAAnimation.animationWithSceneNamed(name: "GameAssets.scnassets/Objects/WalkAnimation.dae")

playerNode.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "WalkAnimation")
```

Answer (score 1):

As we don't have access to your Collada file, let's take the example of `walk.dae` from the [*SceneKitAnimations* sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SceneKitAnimations).

In that file you will find the following:

```
  <library_animations>
    <animation id="WalkID">
      ...
      <source id="node-Bip01_matrix-output">
        ...
        <technique_common>
          <accessor source="#node-Bip01_matrix-output-array" count="29" stride="16">
            <param name="TRANSFORM" type="float4x4"/>
          </accessor>
        </technique_common>
```

You can see that the animation file does not have separate animations for positions and rotations, but instead it has a single animation that targets the whole transforms (cf `TRANSFORM` and `float4x4`).

This means that evaluating the animation will override the `scale` of the node. You'll have to have different animations just for the `position` and `rotation` properties instead of an animation for the `transform` property if you don't want the `scale` to be overridden.